# A Parse PFUser deletes another PFUser

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

my app(written in swift) has login option as a user or as an owner.I have used Parse backend.I want the owner(PFUser) to be able to delete a user(another PFUser)from Parse.However, Parse doesn't allow a user to delete another user.Is there any way I can implement this logic?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer, no that is not possible. Out of curiosity why do you want to do this? Knowing the context might help create an alternative route.

Comment: Thanks Olivier for the reply. I want to do this because I have two types of PFUser, one logs in as a User and other as Admin(Also a PFUser),who can decide who all are users in a particular group. Like, if someone is not adhering to the group policies,admin can remove it.If I assign Role (Parse provides) will that help?

Comment: Is there another alternative route? Please suggest.Thanks again.

Comment: Are there multiple groups in the app? I'd say a better strategy is to put the offending user on a blocked list. Also gives the blocked user the ability to appeal to you/support if they think they've been unfairly blocked.

Comment: No, there is no group in the app.

Comment: But you said there are groups?

Comment: I am sorry for not being able to express my query clearly. There are no groups, based on a Parse Class column boolean value true or false I differentiate and seggregate users and I was referring it as a group. Thank you for your time